# Retaining source files after deploying from Git to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, github, continuous-deployment

I would like to be able to read the the Razor view source files unders the **Pages** folder after deploying my website from the Git repo to an Azure Web App but currently the source files are not retained on Azure after the deployment. Can I modify the yaml workflow file (included below) to stop the source file from being deleted on Azure after the deployment

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Set up .NET Core
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
    with:
      dotnet-version: '7.x'
      include-prerelease: true

  - name: npm install
    run: npm i --save-dev @types/jquery

  - name: Build with dotnet
    run: dotnet build --configuration Release

  - name: dotnet publish
    run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: .net-app
      path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

deploy:
runs-on: windows-latest
needs: build
environment:
name: 'Production'
url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

```
steps:
  - name: Download artifact from build job
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: .net-app

  - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
    id: deploy-to-webapp
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: 'DbNetSuiteCoreApp'
      slot-name: 'Production'
      publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_24DA617B99E54700A670FBE17209D726 }}
      package: .
```